# Executing WinSCP command in batch file

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

I am new to batch and trying to execute a script I wrote, essentially I want to go to a remote server copy the files there and transfer it to a folder in my local directory. I am executing the bactch file but nothing is being copied any suggestions would be great. This is my script

```
open sftp://site:@ftp.site.net -hostkey="server finger print"
synchronize local C:\Users\localdirectory\Desktop\test2    /Home/folderA/NewFiles
exit
```

I am positive all the information is correct because that's how I login with WinSCP. I got this script from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndvEYOQLc4c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is WinSCP script. There's no batch file in your question.

To run WinSCP script, use for example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /script="C:\path\to\winscp.txt"
```

(assuming your WinSCP script is in `C:\path\to\winscp.txt`).

You can put the above command to a batch file.

See [guide to scripting with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

You can also have [WinSCP GUI generate both the script and batch file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script) for you (or even a batch file that directly contains the WinSCP commands).